# How to Select an option in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, junit

Please Help me.

The reason for not able to select the Element is 
when i move to/click  the drop down `id='rfdSubMenu1396697749612'` shows visibility: visible.If i move the cursor away from the dropdown visibility:hidden.

Now when i run the code below it throws No such element id='rfdSubMenu1396697749612' so how to overcome this issue making it visible and selecting an option.

junit code got from Selnium IDE

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_InventoryContent_btnAddSystem")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_InventoryContent_txtAssetName")).clear();
   driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_InventoryContent_txtAssetName")).sendKeys("ASDE346");
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_InventoryContent_txtControlNumber")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_InventoryContent_txtControlNumber"))
        .sendKeys("ASDE346");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.rfdSelectText")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='rfdSubMenu1396538734351']/ul/
         li[2]")).click();
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_InventoryContent_ddlAssetType")))
         .selectByVisibleText("Networking");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Skinnedctl00_InventoryContent_ddlAssetStatus > 
          span.rfdSelectOuter > span.rfdSelectText")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='rfdSubMenu1396538761911']/ul/li[3]"))
          .click();
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_InventoryContent_ddlAssetStatus")))
          .selectByVisibleText("InActive");
```

Changes Made in Junit code

```
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.rfdSelectText")).click();
        // No such Element Present Error occurs in next line
        WebElement dis = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html.RadForm body     
              div#rfdSubMenu1396685935145.rfdSelectBox"));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.executeScript("rfdSelect_selected.click()" , dis);
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_InventoryContent_ddlAssetStatus")))
              .selectByVisibleText("InActive");
```

HTML CODE

```
 <div id="rfdSubMenu1396697749612" class="rfdSelectBox rfdSelectBox_Default" 
    style="overflow-y: auto; width: 149px; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; left: 
    885px; top: 277px; display: none;">
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div/ul/li[2]"))).perform();
act.click().perform();
```

Comment: Please also comment on your code to be more educative.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the exception, element is not visible so Selenium can't interact with it. Make sure element is visible or trigger event which makes the dropdown visible.

Comment: Can u tell how to do that

Comment: Add some relevant code which makes dropdown visible

Comment: Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div/ul/li[2]"))).perform();
    act.click().perform();

Comment: @user3181335: First you should move cursor to dropdown which makes it visible and then select option

Answer (score 0):

As karna has mentioned, some event has to be triggered to make the drop down visible, have you pasted the exact html code,  there might be a hover or click event to make the dropdown visible. You can try a click() event :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("industryType"))).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#industryType option[value='Nt']"))).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#industryType option[value='Nt']"))).click();
```